# find the index of maximum element of 2nd column of a 2 dimensional list

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am a newbie in python,
I need to find the index of maximum element of 2nd column of a 2 dimensional list as follows

3  |  23
7  |  12
5  |  42
1  |  25
so the output should be the index of 42 i.e. 2
I tried converting the list to numpy array and then using argmax, but in vain
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.asarray([[3, 7, 5, 1], [23, 12, 42, 25]])
>>> a
array([[ 3,  7,  5,  1],
       [23, 12, 42, 25]])
>>> a[1]
array([23, 12, 42, 25])
>>> np.argmax(a[1])
2
```